# PHP If Statement to show data after date

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I am working with someone's else's code and am trying to make a simple addition. I have some data in a mySQL database, one of the columns is time_end, which is a date set in the future. I want to show specific text once that date has past.

```
$events = get_all_events();

include 'templates/bet.php';

function get_all_events() {
global $_DB;

$stm = $_DB->prepare('select wl_bet.*, wl_group.gname, (select count(*) from wl_betplace where wl_betplace.betid = wl_bet.id) as countBet from wl_bet, wl_group where wl_bet.groupid = wl_group.gid order by time_end asc');
$stm->execute();
$data = $stm->fetchAll();

$close = array();
$active = array();
$paid = array();

$p = 0;
$c = 0;
$a = 0;
foreach ($data as $d) {
    if ($d['status'] == 2) {
        if ($p < 5) {
            array_push($paid, $d);
            $p++;
        }
    }
    else {
        if ($d['time_end'] < time()) {
            if ($c < 5) {
                array_push($close, $d);
                $c++;
            }
        }
        else {
            if ($a < 8) {
                array_push($active, $d);
                $a++;
            }
        }
    }
}
return array('close' => $close, 'active' => $active, 'paid' => $paid);
}
```

Here is the table I want to show if the current date is past the time_end date. I know this should be as simple as an if statement but I can't seem to get it right. Again all I want to do is show this table once the current date is greater then the date in the mysql database (time_end).

```
 <table width="100%" class="list-details sortable">

                <tr class="tablebar">
                    <th><div>Title</div></th>
                    <th><div>Event Date</div></th>
                    <th><div># of Bets</div></th>
                </tr>
                <?php foreach ($events['close'] as $c) : ?>
                <tr class="row">
                    <td><a href="?cmd=view-bet&id=<?php echo $c['id']; ?>"><?php echo $c['title']; ?></a></td>
                    <td><?php echo format_date_only($c['time_end']); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $c['countBet']; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course 5 minutes after I post this I figure it out

```
<?php if(count($events['close']) > 0):?> text to show <?php endif; ?>
```